# $f: D \to \mathbb{C}, z \to \frac{1}{1+z^3}$ and $\int_{\gamma} f(z) \mathrm{d}z$ - is my argument correct?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I would like to know whether my argument is correct or not. We consider

\begin{align}
f: D \to \mathbb{C}, z \to \frac{1}{1+z^3} \quad \text{and} \quad  \int_{\gamma} f(z) \mathrm{d}z
\end{align}
where $\gamma : [-\pi; \pi] \to \mathbb{C}, \ t \to 2e^{it}$ and $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| > 1 \}$. I would like to decide whether or not $f$ does have a holomorphic antiderivative in $D$.

I argued that the zeros of $1+z^3$ are given by $\{-1, \frac{1}{2} \pm i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\}$ and that they are all not contained in $D$. Therefore $f$ is holomorphic in $D$. Since $\gamma$ is a closed curve and completely in $D$ we have that

\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma} f(z) \ \mathrm{d}z = 0.
\end{align}

Since $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open and $f$ is continuous $f$ does have a holomorphic antiderivative in $D$.

Comment: @MarkViola Ok, that's right. How does that change my argument? Can you give some more details please?

Comment: It's true that $f$ is analytic for $|z|>1$ and that it is analytic on $\gamma$.  That does not mean that $\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz=0$ since there are poles inside $|z|=1$.

Comment: @MarkViola so I have to calculate the residues of the three singularities and if they add up to $0$ $f$ does have a holomorphic antiderivative in $D$ and if they do not $f$ has no holomorphic antiderivative in $D$. Is this the way to go?